# How would I get rid of ios app offloading?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, storage

How to get rid of iOS app offloading ? I don't want apps to be deleted when there's little space left on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > App Store and iTunes > Offload unused apps. Turn it off.